# How do I set the value of another field based on the value selected from a drop down box in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010

I have a view that lists numerous projects; in addition to the project name and assignee, other columns include: % complete, and status. When I set the status column to 'Completed' from a drop-down box, I would like the % complete field to automatically update to 100%. Does anyone have an idea how I can do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are referring to do it by object model.

```
if(dropDown.selectedvalue == "complete")
{
 LabelComplete.text = "100%";
}
```

Here if your %Complete field can be a label or text box . please change it suit your need.

You can also do this by Jquery/Javascript at client side.

Cheers